# External power supply design - Audio Microphone preamplifier . AC vs DC

Tags: power-supply, power

Any outstanding pros and cons of transmitting over short distances (1-2 meters) AC vs DC?

Details: I wish to move the power transformer from a micpre into a small external enclosure to eliminate hum pickup in the device. I could build the entire DC supply in the external enclouser or just send the secondary of the transformer and keep the DC as is; in the device. Any drawbacks to sending the AC voltage? It would be just +/- 20vac and ground of course.

Answer (score 1):

I would move the entire AC section out of our box as you're really not removing the 60/50Hz AC out of your device, you're just reducing the amplitude from 120Vac to 20Vac.  That might make a difference but I would expect you'd see more if you just kept the AC as far away as possible and only had DC going into the device.

But if your AC to DC side is filtered and shielded correctly you should be able to keep it all in the same box.  It sounds like you could have a problem with not blocking AC, or creating a circuit that easily accepts that 60/50Hz noise.

If you can, check for 50/60Hz signals with an oscilloscope on all your DC power rails.  If you're seeing it there you need to improve filtering.  If you're seeing a different frequency then it's not coming from the AC mains section of your power supply.

Hope that helps,

(I'm saying 50/60Hz as AC mains frequency depends on region)

Comment: It appears that the biggest offender is the power transformer itself. As opposed to the other AC to DC components (e.g. rectifier, filter caps, etc.) The mains transformer (toroid) has to sit relatively close to a "gain switch" and the gain switch picks up the magnetic flux. There are sensitive input transformer, that while shielded, obviously not at 100% so they pick up a tiny bit too.

Answer (score 1):

Consider building  the power  supply  inside  a  steel box.

Copper foil does not attenuate 60Hz, nor the very fast edge (10 microsecond) of the rectifier turnon current surges.